# Unable to add images to Telerik Tree View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, telerik, telerik-mvc

Here I'm going to add Telerik Tree View using MVC 4.Tree is populating.But when i tries to add Image, then it failed..

My code goes here

```
    @(Html.Telerik().TreeView()
    .Name("TreeView")
    .BindTo(Model, mappings =>
    {
        mappings.For<myMVCapp.Models.ProjectTree>(binding => binding
                .ItemDataBound((item, node) =>
                {
                    if (item.Text == "News Project")
                    {
                        item.ImageUrl = "~/Content/Images/myimg.png";

                    }
                    item.Text = node.RootNodeText;

                })
               .Children(node => node.ChildNodes)
                );
        mappings.For<MyEntityModel.Project>(binding => binding
                .ItemDataBound((item, subNodes) =>
                {
                    item.Text = subNodes.ProjectName;
                }));
    })
    )
```

Any one have idea about how to add image ?

Comment: I think you need to check `node.RootNodeText` and not `item.Text` so try it with: `if (node.RootNodeText == "News Project")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to compare `item.Text` with something before giving it a value. So inside your `if` expression the `item.Text` will be always `null` so your `item.ImageUrl = ...` line won't be executed.

So do the value assignment before the if:

```
item.Text = node.RootNodeText;
if (item.Text == "News Project")
{
    item.ImageUrl = "~/Content/Images/myimg.png";
}
```

Or use the `node.RootNodeText` in your if:

```
if (node.RootNodeText == "News Project")
{
    item.ImageUrl = "~/Content/Images/myimg.png";
}
item.Text = node.RootNodeText;
```